# Can't use ip_to_hostname from iptools in R take large STRSXP?

Tags: r, iptools

I have been trying to make a new list that has a conversion of IP addresses to their designated domain name.

Since my initial list of IP addresses was List type, I had to do `source_vector <- unlist(source_list)` in order to convert my list into STRSXP (character vector).

Here is what I ran along with a test.

```
source_vector <- unlist(source_list)
test_vector <- c('4.2.2.1', '172.31.3.121')
ip_to_hostname(test_vector)
source_domain_names <- ip_to_hostname(source_vector)
```

Now my problem is that the `test_vector` works fine, giving me an output of:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a.resolvers.level3.net"

[[2]]
[1] "172.31.3.121"
```

I expected to have a new list called `source_domain_names`, which consists of my converted domain names; however, my R freezes, unresponsive at the end.

Is this a normal issue when you try to put large character vector into `ip_to_hostname` function?

Comment: This function seems to be a direct C++ export: https://github.com/hrbrmstr/iptools/blob/32eb8f38378f983b7f035a84bb9974c6cf74527c/src/iptools.cpp#L194-L197

Comment: Are there many duplicates in your inputs? if so, it is more efficient to run this function on _unique_ IPs first

Answer (score 0):

`iptools::ip_to_hostname()` involves DNS resolution and is very slow. From the iptools [documentation](https://hrbrmstr.github.io/iptools/articles/introduction_to_iptools.html#resolving-hostnames):

> Both operations are fully recognised, but aren’t particularly fast - in fact, they’re incredibly slow compared to the rest of the package - since they need to call out of the system to work. For the same reason, they require a net connection to work, and may slow down said connection while running. You’ve been warned.

So when you say "R freezes", probably it is still processing the list (but very slowly).

Comment: I did wait for about 37 hours. I have i7-9900k with 32GB of RAM, but R shouted that the process has been aborted due to unresponsiveness. I guess there is no way to process +30000000 DNS entries using iptools atm in R :(

Comment: You could run `ip_to_hostname()` on incrementally larger vectors (e.g. 10, 100, 1000, etc) and plot whether there is a linear increase in time taken. If so, you could estimate how long you expect the job to take.